# On the utilisation of groupby

Tags: python-3.x, python-itertools

I am trying to understand how groupby works. In fact I try to solve a hacker rank problem ("Compress the String !")

When I look at the discussion, one gives an answer in writing

```
from itertools import groupby

print(*[(len(list(c)), int(k)) for k, c in groupby(input())])
```

and it works. As i understand, the code transform the input into an iterator, and so he run into and print the things he wants.

But when I transform it into

```
from itertools import groupby
iter = groupby(input())
print(*[(len(list(c)), int(k)) for k, c in iter])
```

it doesn't print nothing. I think this is very strange, but essentially due to a lack of knowledge of myself. And I don't understand well the explanation of the python library.

Can someone enlighten me ?

Thanks,
Gautier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]
I want to know how do you run the code? The code is ok when I run it in python3.6

```
Python 3.6.5 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Mar 29 2018, 13:32:41) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> print(*[(len(list(c)), int(k)) for k, c in groupby(input())])
111111232768723648
(6, 1) (1, 2) (1, 3) (1, 2) (1, 7) (1, 6) (1, 8) (1, 7) (1, 2) (1, 3) (1, 6) (1, 4) (1, 8)
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> iter = groupby(input())
1123512433241231
>>> print(*[(len(list(c)), int(k)) for k, c in iter])
(2, 1) (1, 2) (1, 3) (1, 5) (1, 1) (1, 2) (1, 4) (2, 3) (1, 2) (1, 4) (1, 1) (1, 2) (1, 3) (1, 1)
>>>
```

Comment: Excuse me ! I run your code and is ok, I also run your code using itert as name (and not iter) and is also ok.
So retry it, just to be sure, and now it is ok.... (O_o)

This was my previous (and so my actual) code : 
      indice = groupby(input())
      12333234433323332

      print(*[(len(list(c)), int(k)) for k, c in indice])

I understand nothing...

Comment: after review your code, I know your question. groupby is a generator, you need to see the usage of generator, and generator create number just once a time,so the second time is [], there is no data.

Comment: Ok, so two other questions :
this property is for all the itertools ?
is there a way to save the object generated into a variable (in order to not rewrite the code all the time) ?

Thank you very much !

Comment: OK,for the first question, you should see https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html and some itertools is generator, like count, groupby, permutation and so on. for the second question, you can write code like ```indice = list(groupby(input()))``` and it will save the generated data into a variable.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, if you follow exactly these command lines :

```
 indice = groupby(input())

 112222334411122111

 print(*[(len(list(c)), int(k)) for k, c in indice])
```

It will answer you :

```
(2, 1) (4, 2) (2, 3) (2, 4) (3, 1) (2, 2) (3, 1)
```

But if you do exactly these command lines : (just after the answer)

```
  for k in indice :
          print(k)
```

This return nothing (probably a naive code), but the interesting thing, is that if you rewrite your code :

```
  print(*[(len(list(c)), int(k)) for k, c in indice])
```

it will returns nothing

And other interesting thing : writing

```
  print(*[(len(list(c)), int(k)) for k, c in indice])
```

twice (after reseted it) will return nothing the second time (but will return the thing that you wanted the first time). It's like the groupby function could print just once time. This is this thing that I would understand.